# Rearranging text data in excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a table like this:-

```
Item            Model
------------------------
A               10022009
B               10032006
C               05081997
```

I need to rearrange/convert the Model column into this format in excel:-

```
Item            Model
------------------------
A               20090210
B               20060310
C               19970805
```

The Model column is character.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
=RIGHT(B2,4) & MID(B2,3,2)&LEFT(B2,2)
```

Have a look at

- [Left](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php)
- [Right](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/right.php)
- [Mid](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mid.php)

Answer (score 0):

Make a new column with the formula:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(B1,4),MID(B1,3,2),LEFT(B1,2))
```

This will convert the string into a date (assuming the format is initial dd/mm/yyyy)
Next, format the result of this formula with the custom format `yyyymmdd`. This will now be a proper date, formatted as year, month, day.